# How to resize Text View in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm doing some work for the project(Newbie programmer) in SwiftUI.

I try to resize the textbox yet IDK how. Could anyone help me about this?

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var document: NavKov20193123Document
    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $document.text)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            .lineSpacing(3)
            .allowsTightening(false)
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(document: .constant(NavKov20193123Document()))
    }
}
```

Comment: use the `.frame(...)` modifier

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.frame(width: , height: )`

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    return Text("Hello world")
      .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .bold))
      .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
      .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
      .background(Color.yellow)
  }
}
```

[image]